# SDL Timer in C to a char string

Tags: c, timer, sdl

In [Lazy Foo's tutorial](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/22_timing/index.php) about timers he used `std::stringstream timeText;`. However, since I'm coding in C, I was wondering if there was anything similar I can use? Ultimately, if the result gets stored as a string, that would be perfect because I can render it through TTF. Right now, `getticks()` returns a `uint32`; how can I convert that to a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example is just using a string stream in order to then use the << operators to build s string.

In C, you could use, sprintf:

```
char timeText[100];

sprintf(timeText,"Milliseconds since start time %lu", (SDL_GetTicks() - startTime);
.
.
if( !gTimeTextTexture.loadFromRenderedText( timeText, textColor ) )
.
.
```